# got null from the method afterPropertiesSet() unexpectedly

Tags: spring, spring-boot

there were two beans:

> UserService, RoleService

```java
@Service
public class UserService implements InitializingBean{

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("userService starting....");
        System.out.println("cache: "+roleService.getCache());
    }

    public void getCache() {
        System.out.println(roleService.getCache());
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class RoleService implements InitializingBean {


    private String cache;


    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("roleService starting...");
        cache = "String";
    }

    public String getCache() {
        return cache;
    }
}
```

they were **Circular dependencies** and both them implement the interface InitializingBean,start the springboot application then got the logs :

> userService starting....

> cache: null

> roleService starting...

however, when i call the method getBean from applicationContext everything looks ok.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    /**
     * A main method to start this application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        UserService bean = context.getBean(UserService.class);
        bean.getCache();
    }
}
```

the logs:

> roleService starting...

> userService starting....

> cache: String

> String

i think there was the problem about **earlySingletonBeans** ，but i need some Detailed explanation

Comment: There are circulair references, which are bad, there is always 1 bean that isn't fully initialized here and which depends on the order.